# Necesito extraer latitud y longitud de un json de Mapquest y pasarlo por parametro a google maps en javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-maps, mapquest

Necesito extraer con `MapQuest` la latitud y longitud de un `query` que arme en `HTML`, que es el siguiente:

```html
    <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-left: 50px;">
        <dl>
            <h4 style="font-weight: bold;">Ubicación</h4>
            <dt>
                <input type="hidden" id="address" value=" @(String.Format("{0} - {1} - {2} - {3}",
                                                              this.Model.Calle, this.Model.Altura,
                                                              this.Model.localidadesInmueble.nombre,
                                                              this.Model.provinciasInmueble.nombre)) " />
                <output id='map' style="width:700px; height:525px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" />
            </dt>
        </dl>
    </div>
```

Aca tengo mi porción en `Javascript`:

```js
<script>
    // Initialize and add the map
    function initMap() {

        var JsonMapQuest = JSON.parse('http://open.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=X29RTLlDHPGU0ehbx0GMgGg5xMgHlRpL&location=Washington,DC');
        //var JsonMapQuestDecoded = decodeURI($JsonMapQuest);
        
        var lat1 = $jsonMapQuest.results.locations.latLng.lat;
        var lon1 = $jsonMapQuest.results.locations.latLng.lng;
       
        // Posicion del mapa
        var pos = { lat: lat1, lng: lon1 };
        // El mapa, centrado en la posicion
        var map = new google.maps.Map(
            document.getElementById('map'), { zoom: 8, center: pos });
        // El marcador, posicionado en la posicion
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: pos, map: map });
    }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC6wkoi6Gin6a6AemR7HaGuFjGPFizBdWY&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
```

No se si mezcle lenguajes o que, no me funciona.
¿Alguien me podria ayudar?

Comment: Pareciera que has mezclado `PHP` y `JS`, ¿es así?

Comment: Ahora que lo veo si! nunca use PHP asi que no se reconocerlo, pero en JS recien me estoy iniciando y jamas baje un Get de un Json... alguna ayuda para poder usar las funciones de JS ?

Comment: ¿Necesitas una respuesta de solo el `JS` que obtenga los datos de `MapQuestAPI`? Es decir, ¿hacer funcionar `initMap` y nada más?

Comment: Si, solo eso... pasarle por parametro lat y lng a initmap de google maps para ver el mapa en la ubicacion del Address pasado por parametro desde html al JS

Answer (score 0):

El error se debe a que estas mezclando `PHP` y `JS`, tanto sintaxis (*y antes de la primer edición*) como funciones.

Para obtener los datos de `MapQuest Open APIs` con `Javascript` puedes hacer uso de la [`API fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch)

#### Ejemplo:

```js
// Initialize and add the map
function initMap() {

  // Obtenemos la dirección
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;

  // Buscamos los datos
  fetch('http://open.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=X29RTLlDHPGU0ehbx0GMgGg5xMgHlRpL&location=' + encodeURIComponent(address))
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      // Si no hay resultados
      if (!json.results.length) return alert('La dirección no se pudo localizar');

      // Obtenemos las coords
      let latLng = json.results[0].locations[0].latLng;

      // El mapa, centrado en la posicion
      var map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 8,
          center: latLng
        });

      // El marcador, posicionado en la posicion
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map
      });
    })
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC6wkoi6Gin6a6AemR7HaGuFjGPFizBdWY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>

<input type="hidden" id="address" value="Washington,DC" />
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! si habia hecho algunos avances y aprendi muchisimo! ahora pruebo con esto y te digo !

Comment: Ahi carga perfecto el mapa! pero no mueve la posicion de orlando, osea a pesar de no dar ningun error en tiempo de ejecucion debugueando con js, es como que no entra por el metodo showAddress en ningun momento... aun asi estoy recontra cerca de encontrar la solucion gracias a tu respuesta!

Comment: No tengo ningun boton para buscar la direccion, la cargo desde la BD internamente en un div, mira:                                                                
 <input type="hidden" id="address" value=" @(String.Format("{0} - {1} - {2} - {3}",
                                                              this.Model.Calle, this.Model.Altura,
                                                              this.Model.localidadesInmueble.nombre,
                                                              this.Model.provinciasInmueble.nombre)) " />

Comment: @BelgratoSystem, he actualizado mi respuesta. Ahora apenas se llama a `initMap` se busca la dirección en el `input`

Comment: genio total, llego a casa y la pruebo!! increible ayuda me haz dado, y tambien entendi que estaba errado totalmente en mi busqueda

Comment: Funciona perfecto!!! mil gracias !!

Comment: @BelgratoSystem, si te sirvio o te fue de ayuda, considera votarla o marcarla como aceptada.